# Flexibility of number of players in Fluxx

Tags: fluxx

> I've played Fluxx in groups from 2
>   through 10; Zombie Fluxx seems to work
>   even better at the ends of that range.

**[from here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/348/games-that-play-well-with-a-wide-range-of-different-numbers-of-players/379#379)**

The boxes of all the Fluxx games say 2-6 players, but how well do the games play with 7+ players? I have Zombie Fluxx and the regular Fluxx, is there anything I can do to make the game play better with more people? Does anyone with experience of 7+ player Fluxx have any advice? I know combining different versions can often make it impossible to fulfil some goals, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my group, Fluxx tends to end by accident, regardless of number of players.  Actively trying to win pretty much ensures that you won't.  Having lots of players (I think my largest was 10) doesn't seem to change that.  I've had large games end in 5 minutes and I've played in games where we got bored and quit.  I see what you mean by your question though.  Intuitively it seems like a large group would make it harder to win.  In practice, I think there are so *many* ways to win that the number of players doesn't really change the game.

The only group size where Fluxx isn't as much fun is 2.

Answer (score 4):

I have played a few 10-player games of Fluxx and similar to [Kristo's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/fluxx-and-number-of-player-flexibility/1931#1931), the number of players doesn't seem to change the game much.  That said, one drawback is that it may take a LONG time for your turn to come around.