# What are some good 8 player games?

Tags: recommendations

What's a good strategy game for 8 players? Many games can be played by 8 players, but suffer from a loss of pace, and long waits between turns. What games have parallel planning phases, or lots of interaction during turns?

I'm looking for games that can safely be called strategy games, so apples to apples and some other party games don't really count.

This is basically an extension of [this question for 6 players.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/276/recommendations-for-6-player-board-game)

Comment: Hola, need to tighten this up some.  An 8-player game to solve what problem, or set of conditions?  As written, you're looking for everything from Advanced Civilization to Texas Hold'em.  A good question shouldn't have an endless number of answers.  Including a number of potential answers in your question makes this look more suited to a forum than stackexchange.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen this if you can reword it to tell us more about what sort of game you're looking for.  Most games *don't* support 8 players, so this does have the potential to be a useful question.

Comment: Small nitpick, but I have noticed you don't capitalize game titles in your posts, and you randomly hyphenate some of them as well.  I realize I'm probably being pedantic, but improper capitalization is one of those things that drives me up a wall, and it really does make it difficult to pick out game names when you don't capitalize, bold or hyperlink them.

Comment: @Pat @Kristo I've edited the question, did I do any better? :D

Answer (score 7):

I have two 8-player games in my collection that I've brought along to my weekly cafe boardgames group.  (Well, they have variants or expansions that allow 8 players, anyway...)

### Citadels

A good, solid *gamery* game.  I expect the 8-player version would be too intimidating for people who hadn't played before, but it's definitely the sort of game that people can become obsessed over, and want to play again and again.  Individual turns are really quick, and there's a lot of tension in the fact that everyone's role for the turn is secret until it comes around, so there's definitely plenty to hold people's interest while they're waiting for 7 other players to take their go!

### Bang!

Kind of a polar opposite to Citadels, in that I would have no qualms about letting a beginner sit down to the game, but I don't think there's quite as much to hold the long-term interest of dedicated strategy-heads.  Bang! is a lot of fun, as players form alliances (or, more often, get embroiled in vendettas) in a Wild West shootout, where no one is quite sure who is on the Sheriff's side and who wants him dead (Werewolf style).  The one issue with it as an 8-player game is the same one that Werewolf has: it's possible to be knocked out of the game pretty quick, and if that happens it's tough to be just a spectator for the next half hour or more.

ETA: Here's a list of LOTS of 8-player boardgames for anyone interested in really exploring the possibilities: http://boardgamegeek.com/tag/8-player.  Hopefully we have already covered the major contenders between us!

Comment: I've done a large amount of looking through the tag, but many of the games there aren't very good with 8. The fact that a game supports 8 doesn't mean its good with 8. However its a great place to start looking for those rare gems. :D

Answer (score 7):

One of my favorite games for a group of players as large as 8 is **The Great Dalmuti** (by Richard Garfield before he made Magic the Gathering) which is a fantastic and quick card game for large groups (it is based on a game that can be played with regular decks of cards but Dalmuti offers some great modifications that add to the game's enjoyment.

It isn't a full on strategy game so might not be exactly what you are looking for - however there is a lot of skill and because it is a game that resolves quickly - but importantly isn't just a one winner/7 losers game but one where there is a ranking of players based on when you go out each round, it works really well for the right group to play iteratively for how ever long you want to play. It also works well when players may need to drop out for a while and/or join in later (which with large groups is pretty common).

I always play with the rule that the order of physical seating while playing the game is dictated by the game results - this physical movement between rounds adds a lot to the game - not to mention makes it easier to play.

Summary - really fun, iterative, skill but with enough luck to have real swings, and easy for players to join/leave/rejoin and can be played for as long as your group wants to play

Comment: That is a fun game.  Better if you have crowns for the Dalmutis and ugly hats for the Peons, and everyone gets into haughty or servile character.  (Alternatively, have comfy chairs for the Dalmutis and make the Peons sit on the floor!)

Comment: We typically play that the Dalmutis get to pick their seats and everyone else has to sit in order around them. Also that the Greater Peon has to do all the card collection duties. In college when we played the regular card version of the game (President or Kings & Queens) we sometimes played with a drinking game or truth & dare variation - which was both fun & rather dangerous...

Comment: also really really fun when you have a number of couples playing who get competitive with each other - just serious enough to have fun but not so serious that you put relationships at risk

Comment: I have the dilbert version of this http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1814/dilbert-corporate-shuffle

Comment: +1 but I desagree that "It isn't a full on strategy game". I think it is most based on strategy and a bit of random cards, just to challenge your brian/strategy

Answer (score 6):

It is quite difficult find good real strategy game managed to 8 players. But one thing comes to my mind: **[Formula D](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/37904/formula-d)**. It can be played up to 10 persons and it is almost strategy (it has a map at least :-).

[image: Formula D]

Also I can suggest the game loved in my company - **[Saboteur](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9220/saboteur)** (3 to 10 players). It is card game heavy related with bluffing. Where is bluffing factor, strategy comes too :-)

[image]

Comment: +1 was for Formula D. In questions like this, I really prefer to see 1 game per answer. I don't know if that's the official line here, but it seems to work best for me.

Comment: I was thinking should I split answer to separate items but decided not look like reputation-whore who is posting every sentence as new answer :-) (no offense to anybody).

Comment: You don't look like anything nasty when you provide each individual answer as an answer! I think it's more meaningful and more valuable for readers when each answer is separate. Take my comment, "+1 for FD". That doesn't stop Saboteur from floating to the top, even though nobody (at the moment, I am the only upvote) has voted for it!

Comment: @gomad I agree with your opinion.

Answer (score 6):

### [**RoboRally**](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/18/roborally)

RoboRally is played with 8 players and is a free-for-all capture the flag race. Each player takes control of a single robot, but must program their moves 5 turns at a time. This makes the game quite fun with a dash of chaos, as your move for turn 1 will be obvious, but you must start predicting what others will try to do in order to maneuver around in subsequent turns. There is nothing more satisfying than bumping into another player, putting them off course, and watching their carefully pre-planned moves take them into a pit or off the board.

Comment: Wait, you mean the robot who dies the most explosive, hilarious death, *doesn't* win?  ;-)

Comment: If only there were a way to award style points!

Comment: One caveat - you'll want your course to be simpler with that many players, or else you'll be playing forever.

Comment: This is hard enough with 4 people, trying to predict moves in a way where your turn doesnt get blocked, or your robot bumped. I cant imagine it with 8. It seems like almost anything you plan would never happen, making the game more frustrating than chaotically fun.

Answer (score 3):

### Advanced Civilization

This is a great strategy game that can plays well with 4-8 players.  The hardest part is finding a good copy since it's out of print, and you also have to have the original Civilization game, since Advanced is an expansion.  Be warned, it takes a full day to play an 8-player game.

Comment: I'd say 5-8 players, though. Playing with only 4 takes out a lot, since the sea is virtually useless, the players to trade with are only a few, etc.

Comment: @Looris, That could be, I never get to play with that few, just took the recommended off of BGG.

Answer (score 3):

### [Red Dragon Inn](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24310/the-red-dragon-inn)

Red Dragon Inn is the game of what happens after your adventuring party returns from the dungeon. They're flush with treasure and eager to party. Each turn, your character:

- Performs an action, like starting a round of gambling, or stealing a coin, or punching someone
- Buys a drink for a friend
- Drinks

There are three economies in play:
 - Fortitude
 - Alcohol Content
 - Money

Fortitude and Alcohol content start at opposite ends of the same track. Fortitude almost never goes up, alcohol content almost never goes down and when they meet, the character is unconscious.

It's a straightforward game with most of the rules outlined on the player boards and cards. It's got humor, but is best when players 'make their own fun' with voices, in-character banter, or just gleeful play.

You'll need any two Red Dragon Inn sets to play 8 - they play 4 each and mix just perfectly. The third set is coming soon, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

### [The Resistance](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41114/the-resistance)

You could always have a look at The Resistance, a recent publication that easily accommodates that number.  If you've ever played Werewolf or one of its many variants, you'll have a good idea of the type of game play, but it's a social deduction game with some clever bits to it.

Answer (score 2):

### [Tsuro](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/16992/tsuro)

Quick, fairly light game. Very quick to teach new people and can be played even with 7 year olds. Every other players turn is going to change various players' locations, so its pretty riveting and keeps everyone intent on the gameplay.

Comment: I wouldn’t say Tsuro has much strategy when you have so many players. So much happens between your turns it’s effectively random

Answer (score 1):

### [Shadows over Camelot](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15062/shadows-over-camelot) with [Merlin's Company Expansion](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/35704/shadows-over-camelot-merlins-companyr.)

Since its cooperative and you're all working on the same goal, everything that happens when its not your turn is still highly relevant and important, especially if you're the traitor.

Answer (score 1):

### [Blue Max](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/508/blue-max)

Works well with anywhere from 2-21 according to BGG. You're constantly fighting the other players as you skillfully maneuver your various planes, so you need to keep an eye on as many people as possible to be successful.

Answer (score 1):

### [Shadow Hunters](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24068/shadow-hunters)

Kind of like Werewolf as everyone's secretly assigned a role and trying to survive without being killed by the other players, but a bit more involved as there's more character abilities and special items. Very player flexible.

Answer (score 1):

### [Junta](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/242/junta)

The link lists it as only taking seven players, but there are unofficial rules that raise it up to nine.

Most notable for being a game that gets better the more players it has (and gets noticably *worse* the fewer - I wouldn't play with less than five). Most game steps are either simultaneous or involve negotiation, so it's very hard to be left out.

The elevator pitch: Players are leaders of various factions in a banana republic, and must negotiate/intimidate/assassinate each other to get the most foreign aid into their personal Swiss bank account. (It's particularly amusing because it has quite elaborate rules, most of which are merely means to the end of getting the money.)

### [Werewolves of Miller's Hollow](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/25821/the-werewolves-of-millers-hollow)

This one *starts* at eight players and ramps up. Again, everyone is involved in all steps. Advantage is that it ramps straight up to 20 players. Disadvantage is one player usually has to referee.
Elevator pitch: A village tries to out the werewolves in their midst. Each player is a villager, but some are secretly werewolves (and must try to avoid being lynched).

Answer (score 0):

### [Category 5](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/432/category-5) or [slide 5](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31503/slide-5)

The games play exactly the same and have the same cards, they only [vary slightly in the endgame condition](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/392223/why-are-category-5-and-6-nimtz-together-but-not-sl) Both well with anywhere from 4-10, and even potentially up to 12. During the game, player's choose a card from their hands and reveal them simultaneously, so there's no real conception of turns. This also means a 10 player game won't take much longer than a 6 player game.

Answer (score 0):

### [Long Shot](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/40237/long-shot)

Horse racing game for 3-8 players, good amount of strategy.

Answer (score 0):

## Poker

Some may object to a gambling game, but it's easy enough to just give everyone 5K or 10K in chips and play tournament style for the points. Or you could play candy poker: split a big bag of miniature chocolates up to use as chips.

Omaha Hold 'Em is a very exciting game that can play up to 11 (5 table cards, 3 burn cards, and 4 to a person, deals out the whole deck).

Texas Hold 'Em is quite strategic and popular as well, and can actually seat up to 22 people.  Mind you a 22 person Texas Hold 'Em game would be quite random and hard to follow, but you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Memoir '44](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10630/memoir-44) is a scenario-based 2-player game, but if you have either 2 copies of the base game or certain expansions, you can play a 4v4 team game.

I haven't played the team version (called Overlord), but I love the 2-player one and am looking forward to trying it. In the 2 player game, the board is divided into three sections, and my impression is that in the 4v4 Overlord version, 1 player controls each flank and the 4th player is kind of a "general" directing the overall forces.